# How do min_element work with string array and maybe with vector strnig array?

Tags: c++, function

How do min_element work with string array and maybe with vector strnig array? Would you explain me

So, example:

```
class Solution {
public:
string longestCommonPrefix(vector& strs) {

    string min=*min_element(strs.begin(),strs.end());
    string mx=*max_element(strs.begin(),strs.end());}}
```

I could not find answer in google, help me.

Comment: [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) _"...Finds the smallest element in the range [first, last). ... __Elements are compared using operator<__...."_  So for each element in the collection (`std::string` in this case) comparision are made with `operator<` which is defined for `std::string`.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear so anyone trying to help is forced to guess what you are asking about (it probably also explains your lack of luck with google).   Try clarifying your question - and include a valid code sample that illustrates your problem (rather than code which is not valid - the `vector` in your code is clearly not `std::vector`, since `std::vector` is a template class, and cannot be used as it is in your code).

Comment: Easy answer: The same way as with every other type, according to specs.

Comment: Somewhat related: if you need both the smallest and the largest element, use [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) - it finds both in a single pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min_element` and `max_element` use [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) to compare the strings. This operator does a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) comparison of the two strings.

Since you are searching for both *min* and *max*, use [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) instead. That's more efficient than looping through the whole `vector` twice.

```
auto[miniterator,maxiterator] = std::minmax_element(strs.begin(),strs.end());
std::cout << *miniterator<< ' ' << *maxiterator<< '\n';
```

I doubt any of these function will help you to write `longestCommonPrefix` though.

Comment: I saw that some one in answers to the this exercise used this function. I couldn't understand that code, becouse, it must not work.

So, Full code:

https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/discuss/2247320/C%2B%2B-Longest-Common-Prefix-Solution

Comment: I don't think that answer works. Did my answer answer your question _"How do min_element work with string array and maybe with vector strnig array?"_?

Comment: Yes! Thanks more